# Standalone wireless network adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, pager

What I'm looking for is a standalone wireless adapter that connects to a certain network, so that a message can be sent out through the network and this wireless adapter receives it and starts making a beeping noise - consider it to be like a modern version of the traditional 'beeper'/pager.  It needs to be smaller than 10cm if possible (by smaller I mean width).

Comment: @random - perhaps I didn't make myself clear, but I wasn't looking for a specific part or product, but the *sort* of product I should be looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you could use is one of these project boards such as a Raspberry Pi or Arduino with a wireless module (Raspberry Pi you can use a USB mini wifi dongle). The reason I say this is that you need a method of operating the wifi to connect to your network (various encryptions) and a daemon or service monitoring the network for the signal you send so it can react.

Sounds like a good project!

Comment: I was afraid that I'd have to do something like that.  I'd probably use a 'Gumstix' board just because of the size, but if I'm trying to produce a lot of these in a constrained budget, the price factor just isn't working!

Comment: The main hurdles are the wifi connection as you need to manage the SSID, encryption type, negotiation, reconnect, authentication etc and then you need to communicate over the network so an IP stack and the service to read the network to identify your "alarm" signal.